# move the canvas (line) based on outerheight value

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, canvas, html5-canvas

I have created one square and one line using canvas.

Here is the code

```
<canvas id="c4" width="200px" height="150px"></canvas>
<div>
    <canvas id="square" width="200px" height="150px"></canvas>    
</div>
```

Here is the fiddle link.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jkg6P/)

What I want is dynamically i want to move horizontal line in the bottom of the square canvas.

[image]

I got outer height of the square now based on the outerheight i need to set my horizontal line in the bottom of the square.

Thanks in advance
M

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**The line will never be inside the rectangle because the 2 canvas elements don't overlap.**

http://jsfiddle.net/m1erickson/yg9R8/

[image]

You can use Html + CSS to make the canvases overlap and then change the line coordinates so that it will align as desired.

**Html:**  Wrap both canvases in a div

```
<div id=wrapper>
    <canvas id="c4" width="200px" height="150px"></canvas>
    <canvas  id="square" width="200px" height="150px"></canvas>    
</div>
```

**CSS:**  Make the 2 canvases overlap

```
#wrapper{position:relative;}
canvas{position:absolute;}
#c4{z-index:5}
```

**JavaScript** Draw the line and the rectangle

```
var c=document.getElementById("square");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
ctx.rect(20,20,150,100);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.fillStyle ="#f2f2f2";
ctx.fill();


var c4 = document.getElementById("c4");
var c4_context = c4.getContext("2d");
c4_context.beginPath();
c4_context.moveTo(20, 120);
c4_context.lineTo(300, 120);
c4_context.strokeStyle = "Green";
c4_context.stroke();
```

Comment: hi markE thanks for reply but I don't want to use css here it has to move dynamically

Comment: Since the 2 canvas elements will never overlap (without CSS), you can't ever draw a line in one canvas that intersects a rect in the other canvas.  How about just using 1 canvas to draw both the line and the rect?